# Can I send a TCP RST from Delphi's Indy client?

Tags: php, delphi, tcp, indy

We have been experimenting with a Delphi Indy (SVN trunk) client and Apache with mod_php. A PHP script is called which registers a shutdown function.

During testing this shutdown function is called only once the script has ended and `connection_status()` comes back zero.

If I use CURL and hit Ctrl-C during the script's execution, CURL sends a TCP packet with the RST flag set to boolean true. This does trigger the shutdown function and `connection_status()` comes back one. If the connection times out, a TCP FIN flag is switched on but the shutdown function does not trigger - in fact the Apache process goes into CLOSE_WAIT until the PHP script has finished executing. If I use Indy, the only flag that gets set is FIN.

With all this in mind can we get Indy to send a TCP packet with an RST flag set to true? We want to do this when the connection times out (solving the problem we are testing for).

See also http://uk.php.net/connection_handling

Answer (score 0):

Indy always tries to close a connection gracefully, which will not send a RST flag.  If you need that, you will have to forcibly close the connection yourself.

Comment: In our specific case we are seeing a timeout occur. This is handled as an Exception. Can you tell us what we might be able to do? I'm told by the guy that wrote our app that at the point he handles the timeout he believes the connection to be lost already.

Comment: A timeout is a timeout.  Indy does not close a connection due to timeout by itself.  It is possible that the other party could be closing the connection on its end in an abnormal way that does not allow Indy to detect the disconnect right away, and that could lead to timeouts.

Comment: The other side continues executing. In fact in tests it continues to send data to the client. We're clearly missing something. I'll ask our guy to take a further look and perhaps provide a more concise question.

Comment: If you need to send a RST, then you have to force it, such as by turning off the socket's SO_LINGER option and then closing the socket handle.